# citation number after just the Theorem number

Tags: citing

I want to put the citation number like [2] just after Theorem number and no space between them. For example Theorem 1.2.1[7].

Comment: Without spaces? Hum!! Don't you like this: `\begin{theorem}[{\cite[option here]{ref.here}}]`

Comment: it gives Theorem 1.2.1 ( [7]).   I don't want a space before [7]

Comment: `\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}`

Comment: @DeepeshPatel -- in your comment, you say you get "Theorem 1.2.1 ( [7])".  i know where the parentheses come from (and understand that you probably don't want those either), but i've never seen a space *inside* the parentheses before the cited item.  what document class and relevant packages are you using?

Comment: Thanks !  
Can we remove the ( ) bracket ?